# How can I duplicate an image in cloudinary?

Tags: python, django, cloudinary

I am using `cloudinary` with Django, and I need to duplicate an instance of a model which also contains a `CloudinaryField`. I know how to duplicate model instances in Django, but I don't know how to duplicate the image.

This is my model:

```
class CustomImage(models.Model):
    image = CloudinaryField("image", null=True, blank=True)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, auto_now_add=False)
```

This is my duplication code for an instance of that model:

```
image = CustomImage.objects.get(id=1)
image.pk = None
image.save()
```

The problem is that both instances now have assigned the same image assigned, so if I delete one, the other gets deleted. How can I properly duplicate an existing image in cloudinary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to figure it out. Uploading the image with option `overwrite` set to `False` makes the trick. In addition, we need to create a new `CloudinaryResource` and assign it to the `image` field of the `CustomImage` instance.

```py
import cloudinary
from cloudinary import CloudinaryResource

image = CustomImage.objects.get(id=1)
image.pk = None

# cloudinary image duplication
cloudinary_resource = image.image
cloudinary_url = cloudinary_resource.url
response = cloudinary.uploader.upload(
    cloudinary_url, options={"overwrite": False}
)
public_url = response["public_id"]
resource_type = response["resource_type"]
duplicated_image = CloudinaryResource(
    public_id=public_url, resource_type=resource_type
)
image.image = duplicated_image
image.save()
```